# Is there a way to export and import board queries?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to re-use the queries that were build in a specific project in a new project. I am referring to the queries that are available under "My queries". The ultimate goal is to replicate a project dashboard to a new project.

I have been looking for an import and export function, but could not find it.

Comment: Have you tried looking at this? Last time I had checked, personal queries weren't possible to export but haven't tested with the new docs/version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/Queries/Get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to export and import board queries?

For this issue, you could use [Wiql Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor) extension.
[image]

After installing this extension, you can click on the "**Edit query wiql**" option as shown below to enter a page with the "inport" and "export" options.

[image]

[image]

With the **Import** and **Export** options, you can export the query as a .wiq file and import it into another project. You can also refer to this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e936570d-c704-465b-ad14-7a90302ab8d9/can-you-copy-work-item-queries-from-one-collectionproject-to-another?forum=tfsworkitemtracking).Hope this helps.